# Separte view.jsp for each RSS portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I have RSS feeds from 4 different websites grouped logically into two catgeories (Social and educational).I have created 1 RSS portlet for each of the category.Each portlet has link to two URL feeds.

I wanted to customize the look and feel of the feeds while they are displayed.For this I created a hook and modified view.jsp. But what I see is view.jsp changes only takes effect for the 2nd RSS portlet added.

Is there any way I can use the same view.jsp and conditional code for handling display of each of the RSS portlets? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have overridden `view.jsp`, you can also override `configuration.jsp` of the rss portlet. You can add one more select box and give it a name like `preferences--feedStyle--`. Provide number of style options that you want.

This will give you chance to get the configuration to select the style for individual portlet instance of RSS from `Portlet configuration`.

In the `view.jsp`, read the portlet configuration and based on that you can display the desired style.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I will try this and will let you know how it goes.